# ZODB Blob storage

Tags: python, zodb

I require the storage of images in my ZODB database. I was trying to use blobs, but the lack of documentation and examples online has made this very difficult. I don't understand how to use the IBlobStorage interface. I currently make my database as so:

```
storage = FileStorage.FileStorage('DummyData.fs')
db = DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root()
root.users = BTrees.OOBTree.BTree()
```

My first attempt was to make a list of blobs:

```
l = []
l.append(Blob((np.random.rand(1200,1200,3)* 255).astype('uint8').tobytes()))
```

And store this in the Btree(). However, this tree does not support blobs. I cannot figure out how to use IBlobStorage or other storage interfaces and would greatly appreciate some guidance. Any references or links to examples would be sufficient answers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The BlobStorage is essentially an overlay over the regular storage, so you put it on top of that and use it instead.

Here is a pretty minimal example on how to use the BLOB storage in ZODB:

```
import ZODB, ZODB.FileStorage, transaction
from ZODB.blob import Blob, BlobStorage

# Create DB with BLOB
storage = ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage("ZODB_minimal.fs")
blob_storage = BlobStorage("ZODB_minimal_blobs", storage)
db = ZODB.DB(blob_storage)
connection = db.open()

# Create BLOB
blob = Blob()
with blob.open('w') as bf:
    bf.write(b"I am a BLOB!")
    bf.close()

# Put into DB
connection.root.blob = blob

# Close DB
transaction.commit()
connection.close()
db.close()

# Read it back
storage = ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage("ZODB_minimal.fs")
blob_storage = BlobStorage("ZODB_minimal_blobs", storage)
db = ZODB.DB(blob_storage)
connection = db.open()

blob = connection.root.blob
with blob.open('r') as bf:
    text = bf.readline()
    print(text)
    bf.close()

db.close()
```

Hope it helps!